# Odd and Even Permutations and their parities

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

So the question is:

Let Alpha and Beta belong to Sn. Prove that Beta*Alpha*Beta and Alpha are both even or both odd.

I'm not sure where to start. My basic logic class tells me to go with the idea:
                    Alpha=(k-1)=2m
                    Beta=(k-1)=2n+1
But I'm not even sure where else to go from there.

Comment: The proof is very similar to that for numbers: for any two integers $a$ and $b$, the integers $a$ and $b + a + b$ are either both even or both odd.

Comment: Okay so I took your advice and this is what I came up with:

Let Alpha and Beta belong to Sn. Then Alpha ={Alpha1, Alpha2, ..., Alpha(n)} and Beta={Beta(1), Beta(2),..., Beta(m)}
We know that the order of a permutation cycle is equal to the total number of elements in that cycle.
Consider Beta* Alpha* Beta

Comment: = (Beta BLAH BLAH......

Thus we know the order of Beta* Alpha*Beta= order of beta + order of alpha + order of beta

Comment: =m+n+m
=2m+n
Assume alpha is even. Then it follows that the order of alpha is also even and then n= 2k for some integer k

IS THIS OKAY OR SHOULD I ABANDON SHIP?

Comment: You essentially have it, except you should use the word "parity" instead of "order."  That is, parity of Beta*Alpha*Beta = parity of Beta * parity of Alpha * Parity of Beta.  And this is, of course, exactly the same as the answer given below.  By the way, give him a green check - that will get him 15 points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen that there the parity of the permutation is a homomorphism from $S_n$ to $\mathbb Z_2$?

If yes let $p(\alpha)$ be the parity of alpha.

Then $p(\beta\alpha\beta)=p(\beta)p(\alpha)p(\beta)$ which is $p(\alpha)^2p(\beta)$ since $\mathbb Z_2$ is abelian. Which is $0+ p(\alpha)$ since $\mathbb Z_2$ is of order $2$.

Hence $p(\beta\alpha\beta)=p(\alpha)$ as desired

Comment: We haven't covered it yet. I may just read the section ahead to solve it this way. Thank you!